# wifi connectivity problem in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, connection

I have a problem activating my wifi on ubuntu 16.04, I used a debug script and the result is on this link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23967145/ .. any help with this?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules